# How to change Sprite of SpriteRenderer in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just faced to an obsurde problem - I can't change the sprite of SpriteRenderer in script.

```
public Sprite jump_image;

public void Jump()
(
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = jump_image;
)
```

This method is calling by clicking on button.

Any part of the code doesn't influence code above.
This script absolutely attached to gameObject.
To the `jump_sprite` attached image with SpriteRenderer.

I searched in Google about this problem and what I found, didn't help me.
How can I resolve this? Any prompts will help me.

Comment: The code is correct. Either you are not calling your function or you are running into a rouge element interfering. More information is required, in particular on your script and other possible components on your gameObject.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work properly. However,If you're trying to change the sprite in the script outside of a function, it may not work correctly. Move the sprite change code into the Awake or Start method. Or Make sure that the jump_image variable is assigned to the appropriate sprite in the Unity Inspector. If it's not assigned, the sprite will not be changed when you run the code.

```
public Sprite jump_image;

void Start()
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = jump_image;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for careful answer, but it's abvious that I need to call it in function. I'm changing the sprite by clicking on button. But it isn't changing

Comment: Anyways I improved the question

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood You are trying to change this game object sprite to -> **jump_image** when clicking a button.

```
   public void ChangeSprite(){ // This is a method to change sprite


   gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = jump_image;

   }
```

- Then You Have to add a new OnClick event on your button
- add your gameobject that you want to change its sprite  by draging it to the box that takes gameobjects
- Click on the dropdown menu find the class that has the function above
  make sure the function is public
- Find a function called ChangeSprite() and click on it

Hope that Answers your question

Comment: I don't now how is it possible, but in this function I have another code. That code is working correctly but I can't change the sprite, despite of all the code is in the same method. And there is no any errors.

Comment: I made a new project and tested the code you included above and it worked .

Answer (score 0):

I just had  the same Problem right now.

Try defining your sprite as UnityEngine.Sprite.

That could help.